I deposited 110 dollars in Phantom wallet, but my balance in 64 dollars
So I deposited 110 dollars in Phantom wallet with solana, did some swaps for meme coins and now my balance is 64 dollars. Where my money gone? Can someone please help me and explain what is happening?

Presumably the memecoins have dropped in value since you bought them. They have extremely high volatility so that's common.
